# JavaScript 変数代入に変数を記載する書き方

Tags: javascript, html

初歩的質問で申し訳ありません。

htmlファイル間で値の受渡を行いたいのですが、諸々制限があり、webstorage、cookieも使えないので、リンク時にパラメーターをつける事にしました。
パラメーター送信時なのですが
Aという名前の値とBという名前の値を送りたい

Aの値を var a;
Bの値を var B;
にラジオボタン押下の結果をif文にて定義、値代入済みです。

```
var prom =“A=”+a+“&B=”+b;
(上記コードの記載がよくわかっていません)

<a href = “〇〇.html?+pram”;>
```

実行すると、受け側htmlで取得できるのは単純にpramという文字列です。

どう記載したらいいか、ご教授願います。

Comment: 記載漏れがありました。<a href = ”〇〇.html?+prom”;>としています。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　このサイトでは投稿が Markdown として処理されるので、HTML タグっぽい部分が表示されなかったようです。とりあえずコードブロックとして装飾して表示させておきました。他にも不都合があれば本文下の「編集」から自由に書き直せますので、どうぞご利用ください。（たとえば元々の文章だと `prom` と `pram` が混在しているのですが、どちらかが間違いな気がします。また、ダブルクォーテーションもこの形になっていますでしょうか？　お手元のプログラムとよく見比べてみてください。）

Answer (score 3):

HTML文書の中でJavaScriptコードがかけるのは、以下の箇所だけです。

- `<script>`タグ内 / `<script>`からリンクされている外部リソース
- `onclick` などの `on`で始まるイベントハンドラ属性値
- URL用の属性値の中で、`javascript:`で始まる場合

これら以外ではJavaScriptの変数も書くことができません。`a`要素の`href`属性はURL用の属性ですが、`javascript:`で始まらないので変数を書くことはできません。

DOMを使って`href`を変更する必要があります。対象の`a`要素にidを付けるなどしてコードから簡単に参照できるようにして、以下のように属性値を変更します。

```
<a id=foobar>
<script>
var prom = “A=” + a + “&B=” + b;
document.getElementById('foobar').setAttribute('href', '〇〇.html?' + prom);
</script>
```